# vb.net winform 2008 datagrid doubleclick event not firing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, datagridview

i have a databound datagrid in vb.net 2008.  This is a program where i use the double click event multipal times.. but for some reason on a new form it's not working anymore.  In code behind i selected the datagrid and double click event.  when i double click on teh grid in debug mode, it never fires off the event(i put a breakpoint in).  I've tried several other events and none of them are firing.

Here is what the event look like

```
 Private Sub dgWho2_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgWho2.DoubleClick

End Sub
```

and here is what it looks like for one that is working on another form

```
  Private Sub dgQueryStats_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgQueryStats.DoubleClick
    For Each O As asr.QueryStat In Os
        If O.RowID = CInt(Me.dgQueryStats.Tag.ToString) Then
            Me.lblQuery.Text = O.Text
        End If
    Next

    Me.cmdCopyQuery.Visible = True
End Sub
```

in comparing the properties of the two datagrid, other than the name and the binding, they look the same as well.  wondering if anyone has an idea.
thanks
shannon

Comment: Have you populated the Subs that are handling the events and then put a break point on that line?

Comment: yep.. that didn't help.. but i'm seeing something else that might help in providing a solution.. on the other gridviews, when i mouse over a column heading.. it highlights the cell... but not for this one.. so either i haven't set something right or something isn't working right.. my money's on me :)

Comment: i added an event for on Databind complete and that fires.. and the breakpoint works on that one.. wanted to make sure that at least that much was goign on

Answer (score 0):

Err... found my problem.. i had a datagrid.enabled=false stuck down in some code...

Sorry about that
shannon